# PLS-00302: component must be declared- Unable to resolve

Tags: oracle, plsql, syntax-error

I tried the below program in SQL developer and facing some issues:

```
declare
  cursor emp_complex_cur is
    select e.fname,d.dlocation
      from employee e, dept_location d
     where e.dno=d.dnumber;
  emp_max_id integer;
  type emp_complex_rec is record(rname employee.fname%type,rlocation dept_location.dlocation%type);
begin
  open emp_complex_cur;
  for emp_complex_rec in emp_complex_cur loop
    fetch emp_complex_cur into emp_complex_rec;
    dbms_output.put_line('The employee id is: '||emp_complex_rec.rname||' and the employee''s location is '||emp_complex_rec.rlocation);
  close emp_complex_cur;
end;
```

I am getting the error to declare the variable `rname` though it has been properly declared in the record.

Comment: You should consider creating a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) with this.

Comment: I believe there is no Oracle engine available in sqlfiddle.

Comment: @Rahul: Oracle is most certainly supported on SQLFiddle. Go to sqlfiddle.com, click on the database selection (defaults to MySql 5.5.32 but can be changed), and in the resulting dropdown pick Oracle 11g R2. Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
begin
  for emp_complex_rec in (select e.fname,
                                 d.dlocation
                            from employee e
                            INNER JOIN dept_location d
                              ON (e.dno = d.dnumber))
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line('The employee id is: ' ||
                         emp_complex_rec.rname ||
                         ' and the employee''s location is ' ||
                         emp_complex_rec.rlocation);
  end loop;
end;
```

The problem with the original code was that the definition of `emp_complex_rec` as a type was colliding with the definition of `emp_complex_rec` as a cursor loop variable. The explicit cursor definition isn't needed either - IMO putting the `SELECT` in the `FOR` loop is easier and clearer.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

The column's names in your cursor are different from what you're calling in output line, and I guess  that for loop you're using is messing your code. Actually, it could be more simple:

```
declare
  cursor emp_complex_cur is
    select e.fname,d.dlocation
      from employee e, dept_location d
     where e.dno=d.dnumber;
  emp_max_id integer;
begin
  for emp_complex_rec in emp_complex_cur loop
    dbms_output.put_line('The employee id is: '||emp_complex_rec.fname||' and the employee''s location is '||emp_complex_rec.dlocation);
  end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confusing a few different techniques.

---

### Option #1 - Explicit cursor fetched manually

```
declare
  cursor emp_complex_cur is
    select e.fname,d.dlocation
      from employee e, dept_location d
     where e.dno=d.dnumber;
  emp_max_id integer;
  type emp_complex_typ is record(rname employee.fname%type,rlocation dept_location.dlocation%type);
  --A variable must be declared of the type you've created
  emp_complex_rec emp_complex_typ;
begin
  open emp_complex_cur;
  --Initial fetch is needed
  fetch emp_complex_cur into r_complex_rec;
  while emp_complex_cur%found loop
    fetch emp_complex_cur into r_complex_rec;
  end loop;
  close emp_complex_cur;
  dbms_output.put_line('The employee id is: '||emp_complex_rec.rname||' and the employee''s location is '||emp_complex_rec.rlocation);
end;
```

---

### Option #2 - Explicit cursor fetched using `for` loop

```
declare
  cursor emp_complex_cur is
    select e.fname,d.dlocation
      from employee e, dept_location d
     where e.dno=d.dnumber;
begin
  --no "open" required
  for emp_complex_rec in emp_complex_cur loop
    --no "fetch" required
    null;
  end loop;
  --no "close" required
  dbms_output.put_line('The employee id is: '||emp_complex_rec.rname||' and the employee''s location is '||emp_complex_rec.rlocation);
end;
```

---

### Option #3 - Implicit cursor fetched using `for` loop

See the answer provided by @BobJarvis

---

### Option #4 - Explicit cursor fetched only once

For this kind of scenario where you're only retrieving a single record, I prefer to use an explicit cursor and a single fetch. It doesn't matter if your query is returning 1 row or 100, since you're only acting on one. Why iterate through all of the rows you're going to ignore?

```
declare
  cursor emp_complex_cur is
    select e.fname,d.dlocation
      from employee e, dept_location d
     where e.dno=d.dnumber;
  emp_complex_rec emp_complex_cur%rowtype;
begin
  open emp_complex_cur;
  fetch emp_complex_cur into r_complex_rec;
  close emp_complex_cur;
  dbms_output.put_line('The employee id is: '||emp_complex_rec.fname||' and the employee''s location is '||emp_complex_rec.dlocation);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Allan for the detailed answers! I am still facing issues even after using the record type as mentioned in option #1. I am in need of displaying all rows which satisfies the condition (employee id in employee table=employee id in department table). I was trying to achieve this through the way mentioned in option #2. But I am still getting the same error when i run the code given in option #2. Thoughts please?