# encountering "PLS-00302: component 'QUANTITY' must be declared" although the column 'quantity' is declared in the table

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, sum, oracle10g

I was trying to iterate over a cursor to get some values and my approach was similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22309450/8192914). And the code is as follows:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE
    sold_phone_id Sale.phone_id%TYPE;
    sold_count number;

BEGIN
    FOR row IN (
                SELECT Sale.phone_id, SUM(Sale.quantity)
                FROM Sale
                GROUP BY Sale.phone_id
            )
    LOOP
        sold_phone_id := row.phone_id;
        sold_count := row.quantity;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sold_phone_id || ' ' || sold_count);
    END LOOP;


END;
/
```

However, I'm encountering the following error:

```
 sold_count := row.quantity;
                                  *
ERROR at line 13:
ORA-06550: line 13, column 21:
PLS-00302: component 'QUANTITY' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 13, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

I've declared my Sale table in the following way:

```
CREATE TABLE Sale(
    id number,
    phone_id number,
    quantity number,
    sale_date date,
    seller_id number,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(seller_id) REFERENCES Seller(id)
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your subquery does not return this column. Use an alias for the `sum()`:

```
BEGIN
    FOR row IN (
                SELECT phone_id, SUM(quantity) as quantity   --> here
                FROM Sale
                GROUP BY Sale.phone_id
            )
    LOOP
        sold_phone_id := row.phone_id;
        sold_count := row.quantity;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sold_phone_id || ' ' || sold_count);
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: **Just a bit of caution**. ROW  is actually listed as an [Oracle reserved word](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/ap_keywd001.htm#SQLRF55621) and byANSI SQL standard (SQL:11 and SQL:16 ). While it presents no harm now Oracle could decide to use it in a very specific manner, especially if the SQL standard does so, that would invalidate your usage.  That could create a very confusing error. In short it is best to avoid any word listed.  Try:  select * from v$reserved_words;

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code part in for loop query:
**SUM(Sale.quantity) AS TEMPVARIABLE**

Then use **row.TEMPVARIABLE** instead of **row.quantity** at line 15.